# LDL' factorization errors when increasing dimensions

Tags: c, matrix, rounding, precision, factorization

This is probably a more discussion oriented question. My code is working but I see some results that are a bit specific and can't really pinpoint the reason.

So I have made a LDL' factorization and am testing it by reconstructing the factorised matrix A and then comparing to the original. That is

Doing the following steps:

1. Factorize A into L and D, A=L*D*L'
2. Reconstruct A by the matrix L and D, A_re = L*D*L'
3. finding the error by taking the 2 norm of A-A_re, ||A-A_re||_2.

Then doing this for different dimensions of A and multiple times for each dimension. From this I then get a visual representation as follows of the error.

[image]

So clearly the error increases when the dimension of the matrix A also increases. This was expected and just to detail a bit double precision is used in C. All work is done on a Mac OS machine with 8 gen I5 intel processor.

As stated, I was expecting the error to increase but was expecting a more gradual increase and not the "bumbs" that are seen at n=125, n=250, and n=500. Can any of you guys explain what may be happening?

Comment: Rounding errors for floating-point types on computers *compound*. You start with little, then its gets progressively worse the more calculations you perform. Much like the graph shows.

Comment: Yeah, that was expected, I was more specially qustioning if there is a reason for the increase of growth rate, seen in the interval n=240 to n=270, and then again slower increase of the errors.

Comment: How are the various A constructed? It might be informative to scale the error by the condition number of A.

Comment: The a is constructed by generating a n x n matrix (X) of positive scalars, then A=X'X +I, I being the identy matrix exactly to decrease the conditioning number.